# How to fix CentOS 5.5 update dependency?

Tags: centos, perl, yum

It always has this problem.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Net::SSLeay) >= 1.33 is needed by package perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Net::SSLeay) >= 1.33 is needed by package perl-
AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

I tried to install perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm

But it cannot be fixed.

```
[root@hosted-by pear]# rpm -ivh perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(EV) >= 3.05 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(Guard) >= 1.02 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(JSON) >= 2.09 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(JSON::XS) >= 2.2 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(Net::SSLeay) >= 1.33 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
```

Comment: Did you try using the suggest package-cleanup ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the suggested fix at http://mattdanger.net/2010/12/perl-net-ssleay-dependency-error-when-installing-memcached-with-yum/ would help.

But I'm not an rpm user, so be careful.

Comment: I followed these setps , but it still can't be fixed .[root@hosted-by pear]# rpm -ivh perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(EV) >= 3.05 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(Guard) >= 1.02 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(JSON) >= 2.09 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(JSON::XS) >= 2.2 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(Net::SSLeay) >= 1.33 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch